# How can I programmatically get a checkbox value?

Tags: 8, forms

[image: Get Checkbox Value programatically]

I need to check if "Close this ticket after replying" checkbox is checked or not. The value $ab is not getting displayed. This is a comment type created from **Structure > Comment Type**.

```
function helper_ticket_comment_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
          $ab = $form_state ->getValue('field_close_this_ticket'); 
           \Drupal::logger('CheckBoxValue')->notice($ab);
           
 }
```

> Error:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and then use its `dpm()` function to print a variable to the message area of your page. So inside your submit handler put `dpm($form_state->getValue('field_close_this_ticket'));` and you'll see what the error message already is telling you: It's an array. While the logger expects a string. What you are looking for is inside `$form_state->getValue('field_close_this_ticket')['value']`, note the `['value']` at the end.

```
function helper_ticket_comment_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  if ($form_state->hasValue('field_close_this_ticket') && $form_state->getValue('field_close_this_ticket')['value'] == TRUE) {

    \Drupal::service('messenger')->addMessage(t('Ticket closed'));
  }
}
```